# Validating a foreign key field with non-Primary Key in a serializer django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using the Django Rest framework to create an API. I have the following models:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    exchange_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
```

and here is the serializer for the API request-

```
class WalletCreditSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    wallet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all())
    amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    currency = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Currency.objects.all())
    message = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, allow_null=True)
```

The serializer works well when I am passing currency id in request

```
{
    "wallet": 1,
    "amount": 23,
    "currency": 1,
    "message": "Test message"
}
```

But the requirement is the pass the Currency code

```
{
    "wallet": 1,
    "amount": 23,
    "currency": "USD",
    "message": "Test message"
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? Could someone provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using 'pk_field' param from 'PrimaryKeyRelatedField'

```
currency=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Currencies.objects.all(), pk_field='code')
```

or by using 'CharField' and validation like this:

```
class WalletCreditSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    wallet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all())
    amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    currency = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, allow_null=False)
    message = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, allow_null=True)

    def validate_currency(value):
        currency = Currencies.objects.filter(code=value).first()
        if not currency:
            raise ValidationError("error message here")
        returnt currency
```

Comment: I am not able to achieve the output using pk_field. It's throwing the error  ==> **'str' object has no attribute 'to_internal_value'**

Comment: validate_currency method did the work done.

Comment: First solution is wrong. DRF documentations states that `pk_field` is about serialization of the pk field, it does NOT work as selection of the primary key field other than the pk.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: I can confirm that second solution works. (I cannot edit the above command)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the field `currency` of your serializer to `CharField` and add a create method in your serializer to which will get the actual object of string ***USD*** provided in field `currency`.

```
class WalletCreditSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        wallet = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Wallet.objects.all())
        amount = serializers.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
        currency = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, allow_null=False)
        message = serializers.CharField(max_length=150, allow_null=True)
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            validated_data['currency'] = Currencies.objects.get(code=validated_data['currency'])
        except Currencies.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Please provide the valid option for currency')

        return Model.objects.create(**validated_data) #remember to replace 'Model' with your actual model name.
```

Also, in your ***models.py*** you have crated model with the name `Currency` and in your serializer for field `currency` you have used the related model name as `Currencies`. I am not sure which one of those model persist the object for string ***USD***.

Comment: Name Currencies was a typo. I have edited the question. Thanks